# How do I specify a host for mqtt nodes in node-red?

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I am keen on knowing how can I specify a host in node-red `mqtt in` node, let's say that my command line would be like this

`mosquitto_sub -h <Region>.thethings.network -t '+/devices/+/events/activations' -u '<AppID>' -P '<AppKey>' -v`

How can I set the host part `-h <Region>.thethings.network` in the mosquitto node that node-red provides?

So far I have using this nomemclature `<AppID>/devices/+/up` as topic, but now I don't know where to add the host part.

Thanks in advance,

Kind regards!

Answer (score 2):

The MQTT in and out nodes share a set of config nodes that contain the information about connecting to the broker.

If you click on the pencil icon at the end of the Server property in the editor

[image]

This will open a new config section that you can enter all the broker details.

[image]

Because these are shared you only need to add the details once, then you can just select them from the Server drop down list in the original node config.

Comment: so in my case the host parameter, should be the `Client ID` that is shown in your second picture, right?

Comment: Given the answer from @hardillb answers you question, please consider accepting it